# Skype4COMLIB skype.message.chat.sendmessage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, skype4com

I have a problem with my c# code I am trying to change the group chat topic
but it does not work

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Skype skype = new Skype();
        skype.Message.Chat.SendMessage("/topic " + textBox9.Text);
    }
```

and when I press the button it says unknown message

Comment: Have you checked if `textBox9.Text` is correct? Perhaps you should consult the documentation of Skype4COMLIB

Comment: textBox9.Text is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach skype with skype.attach();
You should make 1 global skype object and on your form load you should attach skype.

Comment: You're not defining what chat to send the message to, which can be done like so for convos: skype.Chat(ChatName).SendMessage(Message)
To get convo name in skype, open the chat with skype client and type in the chat /showname and copy the whole name,Remember that you can't use it for contacts tho, for contacts use Skype.sendmessage(contact,message)

If you want to loop through all chats on client you can do something like this:

    `for i as integer = 1 to skype.chats.count -1
     dim chat = skype.chats(i)
    ' do something with chat
    next`

Comment: I wanted to use it for a group chat that's why is says /topic

Comment: I know its for a group chat, and I already explained you on the message how to send messages to group chats by skype.Chat(ChatName).SendMessage(message)

Comment: skype.Chat(ChatName).SendMessage(Message) I tried it but it says chat cannot be used as a method